# How to addClass as partial part from parent class

Tags: jquery

I've this code and want to copy the numbers 1,2,3... of the classes gal1. gal2, gal3.. together with the addClass "featured-image". It can't be counted, because the classes ga1, gal2, gal3.. are insertet manualy with no order. So I've to fetch the number of parent class galX and addClass to a.featured-imageX.

```
$('.gal1').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass( 'featured-image1' );
$('.gal2').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass( 'featured-image2' );
$('.gal3').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass( 'featured-image3' );
$('.gal4').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass.....and so on.
```

I've searched and thought about it, but still no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```js
$('div[class^="gal"]').each(function(){
    // in here $(this) is the div[class^="gal"] element
    $(this).find('a[href]').addClass(
        'featured-image' + 
        $(this).attr('class').replace (/[^\d.]/g, '')  // get the number from the classname from div[class^="gal"]
    );
});
```

```css
/* only to show the class with the number gets added */
.featured-image1 { color: orange; }
.featured-image2 { color: green; }
.featured-image3 { color: fuchsia; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gal1">
    <div class="blubb">
        <p><a href="#">A TAG</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="gal2">
    <div class="blubb">
        <p><a href="#">A TAG</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="gal3">
    <div class="blubb">
        <p><a href="#">A TAG</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the solution. Thank you caramba.This regex im not familiar to. ".replace (/[^\d.]/g, '')". What's being replaced? The "nothing" after featured-image?

Comment: @AchimUdo in the first iteration we pass the string `gal1` to [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) Paste in your console or read it like: `'gal1'.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')` Replace replaces everything from `gal1` which is not a digit (number) with a space. Try `'gal1'.replace(/[^\d.]/g, 'X')` in your console. Learn more about regexes `/[^\d.]/g` [here](https://regex101.com/r/mcGheA/1/)

Comment: @AchimUdo actually "Replace replaces everything .... digit (number) with a space" is actually wrong it replaces it with nothing so maybe it replaces it with an "empty space" ..

Comment: Now I added a second class (class="testclass gal1") and it wont't work anymore. So I found that [class*="gal"] instead of [class^="gal"] does the trick.

Comment: @AchimUdo of course the `^` makes sure the class has to start with `gal` whereas the `*` matches everything with `gal` also `xgalY` will also match with `*`. So be careful with it! see here https://jsfiddle.net/u7josgdy/4/ or why not use `class="gal1 testclass"`?